# Styled Components Not Initially Working on a Gatsby Project

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I have an input field that I have styled with Styled Components.  As far as I can tell, everything is fine and it should work without any problems.

However, when I load the page, the input field load with the default browser styles.  Only if I make a change to the code will the proper styles show up with hot reloading.

I have made a video showing the problem in case that helps:  https://www.loom.com/share/3f9c7a8e7b7a4a85a93332761ea65e2f

In case it is relevant, this is a Gatsby site.

Also, in case it helps -- here is a CodeSandbox link to the project:  https://codesandbox.io/s/fresh-cms-version-003-z2724?fontsize=14

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Does this happen when you don't use codesandbox?